# Multiple forward declarations inside a function

Tags: c, function, declaration

Why is the following code allowed by C99:

```
int main (void)
{
    int add (int, int);
    int add (int, int);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought tentative definitions concern global variables only (variables with file scope).
This indicates that those forward declarations are not treated like variable declarations.

It does not yield any error or warnings with GCC  `-Wall -Wextra -Werror=shadow -std=c99`
which means it is most likely either compliant with the standard (for some odd probably historic reason) or as an language extension of some sort. Is it required by the standard, what is its purpose?

I am hoping to understand function declarations and definitions within block scope completely, so that certain error/warning messages make sense.

Comment: You can have as many of the same function prototype as you want as far as I know.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yep, I figured that out, but the question is why and how the compiler interprets it. It is odd. If I then define the function within the same scope, it fires this weird error like "static declaration of ‘add’ follows non-static declaration" which behavior is hard to explain with examples where this happens with other constructs.

Comment: [You can have many declarations of (global) variables as well](https://godbolt.org/z/jTacoohfK). For tentative definitions one of them will become the actual definition and the others will remain declarations. If there's one explicit definition (like e.g. `int foo = 123;`) then all the rest will be just declarations.

Comment: A function prototype declares what's important about a function that will be called. Since functions _live_ at "file scope", what you've shown is meaningless (and, apparently harmless.)

Comment: Declarations of variables differ from declarations of functions. Function declarations are never tentative definitions (how could they be?). They're just declarations and with and implicit `extern` unless they're declared `static`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware of that, but this code does not show anything related to the question.

Comment: Function _definitions_ in a block scope aren't an thing in C. GCC does have an extension that supports them, but then you have to look at its docs to understand exactly what they do.

Comment: @Mat Seems like MinGW GCC supports function definitions in a block scope, but that is not the issue.

Comment: in Visual C _warning C4210: nonstandard extension used : function given file scope_

Comment: *"it fires this weird error like "static declaration of ‘add’ follows non-static declaration""* If you want to understand why you get weird errors, you need to post the code that generates those errors. See [mcve].

Comment: @user3386109 Well, that was just a comment. I will understand those errors if there is a good answer on this question.

Comment: @Edenia - As to the "why" - the language standard specifies what a function declaration looks like, but it doesn't say "there can only be one". (And don't spend too much time on learning something that you will use about once every 10 years. Instead read up on it when/if ever needed).

Comment: @BoP Actually I am required to know exactly how this works for the project I am working on, but generally speaking you're right :)

Comment: To remain compliant with Standard C, you will not define (as opposed to declare) functions inside the scope of another function.  Functions defined within a function cannot be accessed by name from outside that function; they are effectively `static` functions.  That's likely the source/cause of the "weird error" you refer to.  Personally, I'd not use nested functions except under extreme duress.  (GCC supports nested functions as a non-standard extension to C; you should read the GCC documentation on [Nested Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).)

Comment: I think part of the reason it's accepted is because of the fact that there are no specified parameters in either function declarations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are nested function declarations implicitly 'extern' like the file-scope function declarations? the GNU GCC documentation on nested function only says that nested functions (assuming declarations) have no linkage. If they are not 'extern' then they seem to be most likely subject to the implicit declaration rule kept for backwards-compatibility ..?

Comment: If you want to forward declare a nested function, you need to use `auto` according to the documentation I linked to previously.

Comment: And nested functions are most nearly similar to 'static' — they are not visible by name outside the function where they are defined.  There are (documented) limitations on how you can pass pointers to such functions around, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see. I do know how it behaves, I am more particularly interested in the technical details though. For instance - are the nested function (definitions) implicitly 'static'. If that was the case, then adding 'static' to them would make no difference, but instead the compiler issues an error. It is a bit confusing, since the error report from earlier deems it "static declarations". Also, I am convinced that all function declarations regardless of whether they are in block scope or file scope are implicitly 'extern'.

Comment: Read the documentation on nested functions — I've already pointed you to it.  It says that you can't apply either `static` or `extern` to nested functions.  Nevertheless, they do not have any linkage, a technical term you need to understand.  It means you cannot refer to the nested functions by name from outside the function where they're defined.  This is somewhat similar to what happens with `static` to file scope functions — you can't refer to them by name from outside the TU (translation unit) that defines them.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  If you're not clear about the meaning of the technical terms, you need to study them.  The C standard specifies what linkage means, albeit not in the context of nested functions (it doesn't recognize the possibility of nested functions).  See C11 [§6.2.2 Linkage of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the following code allowed by C99:

`int add (int, int);` is only a declaration; it says “There is a function named `add`, which external linkage, that takes two `int` parameters and has an `int` return type.”

Repeating this declaration does not conflict with the prior declaration—if you say a thing twice, there is no conflict. C allows it largely because repeated declarations may easily occur when headers include other headers, so it is easier to allow repetitions than to require multiple programmers to coordinate their headers so that no repetition occurs.

If a declaration were a definition that creates an object or a function, there could be problems since then you have multiple instances of a thing. So there are more involved rules for definitions. But simple declarations generally can be repeated.

> I thought tentative definitions concern global variables only (variables with file scope).

A tentative definition is for objects only. C 1999 and C 2018 6.9.2 2 say:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*…

So tentative definitions are not relevant to the code in this question.

Comment: I've gotten it cleared up already, but thank you nonetheless. Still useful. (: