# GCC: non-static declaration of function follows static declaration, but declared with 'auto'

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

```
int main (void)
{
    auto int func (int a);
    int func (int a); // <-- concerned line
}
```

I am working on a static analyzer, or so to speak. I have to understand the underlying reason as to why the compiler behaves this way.

Why does GCC issue the following error:

> error: non-static declaration of ‘func’ follows static declaration

What makes `auto int func (int a);` a "static declaration"?

Comment: You forward declare `func` to be a nested function with the GCC `auto` extension, and you also declare it as an `extern` function (without the keyword `extern`) on the "concerned line". If you defined `func` instead of declaring it again, you would not get the error. I helped you [extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76768603/15168) with similar issues; it appears you have still not understood what it says about [Nested Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) in the GCC manual.  I know of no better source of information than that page.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think we are not understanding each other correctly for which it could very well be my bad. All in all, I appreciate and respect what you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely using GCC in a mode that does not conform to the C standard, likely its default mode. When you add `-pedantic`, GCC complains that the first declaration, `auto int func (int a);`, is improper.

In standard C, a function should not be declared with `auto`. For declarations at block scope, C 2018 6.7.1 7 lists the restriction:

> The declaration of an identifier for a function that has block scope shall have no explicit storage-class specifier other than `extern`.

And for declarations at file scope, 6.9 2 lists the constraint:

> The storage-class specifiers `auto` and `register` shall not appear in the declaration specifiers in an external declaration.

When the switch `-pedantic` is used, GCC issues the diagnostic “invalid storage class for function 'func'”.

GCC has an extension that allows nested function definitions. You can define a function inside another function (and capture some context from the enclosing function). When `-pedantic` is not used, GCC may be allowing the `auto` keyword to pass as part of this nested function feature. Then I suspect the “non-static declaration of ‘func’ follows static declaration” message is a slight bug in the implementation of this feature.

I suspect, without much grounds other than general experience, the bug is of this nature: In standard C, `func` would have been declared previously only with `static` or `extern` or no storage class specifier (equivalent to `extern`), so there are only two options: `static` or `extern`. The code that was written to process `int func (int a);` was written with standard C in mind, and it is constructed to test whether the identifier was declared as `extern` and, if not, to issue that diagnostic message about previously being declared static. That is correct code for standard C but fails to account for the third option that is possible with GCC’s nested function extension.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful and informative answer. (`extern` is meaningless in function declarations I think, as it is implicit)

Answer (score 3):

> What makes `auto int func (int a);` a "static declaration"?

With respect to the language spec: compiler whim, which it is free to indulge because the program has undefined behavior.  It violates this provision:

> The declaration of an identifier for a function that has block scope shall have no explicit storage-class specifier other than `extern`.

(C23 6.7.1/8; substantially the same text also appears in earlier versions of C)

Comment: What do you mean by substantially it appears in earlier versions of C?

Comment: @machine_1, I mean that earlier versions of the spec have provisions with similar text and the same effect, though not necessarily numbered the same.  In fact, it looks like I was a bit lazy with that "substantially": the exact same text appears in every version of standard C.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It is a constraint in 6.9, for external declarations. I misread it in 6.7.1, for block scope.